# Get All Route (Module, Controller, Action) in Yii2 Aplication

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i want to get all route from my aplication in Yii2 Advanced.
i was finish this problem but, i want to make it match with directory.

my code for frontend/modules and everything inside this:

```
    $dir = Yii::getAlias('@frontend');
$getFile = \yii\helpers\FileHelper::findFiles($dir,['only'=>['*.php']]);
$files['controllers'] = [];
$files['modules'] = [];
foreach($getFile as $file){
    if (substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') - 6) == 'Module.php') {
        $mname = strtolower(str_replace('Module','',basename($file,".php")));
        $mfilename = basename($file,".php").'.php';
        $mpath = str_replace($mfilename,'',$file);
        $mroute = '/'.str_replace('Module','',$mname);
        $files['modules'][$mname]['path'] = $mpath;
        $files['modules'][$mname]['filename'] = $mfilename;
        $files['modules'][$mname]['route'] = strtolower($mroute);
        $getFileCont = \yii\helpers\FileHelper::findFiles($mpath,['only'=>['*.php']]);
        foreach($getFileCont as $file){
            if (substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') - 10) == 'Controller.php') {
                $cname = strtolower(str_replace('Controller','',basename($file,".php")));
                $cfilename = basename($file, ".php").'.php';
                $cpath = str_replace($cfilename,'',$file);
                $croute = $mroute.'/'.str_replace('Controller','',$cname);
                $files['modules'][$mname]['controllers'][$cname]['path'] = $cpath;
                $files['modules'][$mname]['controllers'][$cname]['filename'] = $cfilename;
                $files['modules'][$mname]['controllers'][$cname]['route'] = strtolower($croute);
                $content = file_get_contents($file);
                preg_match_all('#function action(.*)\(#ui', $content, $aData);
                $files['modules'][$mname]['controllers'][$cname]['actions'] = [];
                foreach($aData[1] as $action){
                    $act = strtolower($action);
                    // $files['modules'][$mname]['controllers'][$cname]['actions'][$act]['name'] = $action;
                    // $files['modules'][$mname]['controllers'][$cname]['actions'][$act]['function'] = 'function'.$action;
                    $files['modules'][$mname]['controllers'][$cname]['actions'][$act]['route'] = strtolower($croute.'/'.$action);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is code for frontend/siteController:

```
$getFileController = \yii\helpers\FileHelper::findFiles($dir.'/controllers',['only'=>['*.php']]);
foreach($getFileController as $file){
    if (substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') - 10) == 'Controller.php') {
        $cname = strtolower(str_replace('Controller','',basename($file,".php")));
        $cfilename = basename($file, ".php").'.php';
        $cpath = str_replace($cfilename,'',$file);
        $croute = '/'.str_replace('Controller','',$cname);
        $files['controllers'][$cname]['path'] = $cpath;
        $files['controllers'][$cname]['filename'] = $cfilename;
        $files['controllers'][$cname]['route'] = strtolower($croute);
        $content = file_get_contents($file);
        preg_match_all('#function action(.*)\(#ui', $content, $aData);
        $files['controllers'][$cname]['actions'] = [];
        foreach($aData[1] as $action){
            if($action !== 's') {
                $act = strtolower($action);
                $files['controllers'][$cname]['actions'][$act]['route'] = strtolower($croute.'/'.$action);
            }
        }
    }
}
print_r($files);
```

output value is:

```
Array
(
    [controllers] => Array
        (
            [site] => Array
                (
                    [path] => /var/www/html/aoisora/_protected/src/frontend/controllers/
                    [filename] => SiteController.php
                    [route] => /site
                    [actions] => Array
                        (
                            [index] => Array
                                (
                                    [route] => /site/index
                                )

                            [login] => Array
                                (
                                    [route] => /site/login
                                )

                            [logout] => Array
                                (
                                    [route] => /site/logout
                                )

                            [contact] => Array
                                (
                                    [route] => /site/contact
                                )

                            [about] => Array
                                (
                                    [route] => /site/about
                                )

                            [signup] => Array
                                (
                                    [route] => /site/signup
                                )

                            [requestpasswordreset] => Array
                                (
                                    [route] => /site/requestpasswordreset
                                )

                            [resetpassword] => Array
                                (
                                    [route] => /site/resetpassword
                                )

                            [verifyemail] => Array
                                (
                                    [route] => /site/verifyemail
                                )

                            [resendverificationemail] => Array
                                (
                                    [route] => /site/resendverificationemail
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [modules] => Array
        (

            [post] => Array
                (
                    [path] => /var/www/html/aoisora/_protected/src/frontend/modules/blog/modules/post/
                    [filename] => PostModule.php
                    [route] => /post
                    [controllers] => Array
                        (
                            [default] => Array
                                (
                                    [path] => /var/www/html/aoisora/_protected/src/frontend/modules/blog/modules/post/controllers/
                                    [filename] => DefaultController.php
                                    [route] => /post/default
                                    [actions] => Array
                                        (
                                            [index] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [route] => /post/default/index
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [blog] => Array
                (
                    [path] => /var/www/html/aoisora/_protected/src/frontend/modules/blog/
                    [filename] => BlogModule.php
                    [route] => /blog
                    [controllers] => Array
                        (
                            [default] => Array
                                (
                                    [path] => /var/www/html/aoisora/_protected/src/frontend/modules/blog/controllers/
                                    [filename] => DefaultController.php
                                    [route] => /blog/default
                                    [actions] => Array
                                        (
                                            [index] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [route] => /blog/default/index
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

the problem is : **[route] => /post/default/index** must to be **[route] => /blog/post/default/index**
because post is available in blog modules. i use method with file helper, every file with name ..Module.php or ..Controller.php it can be return value.

Answer (score -1):

Had same issue, made this code (post in controller action):

```
$controller = \Yii::$app->controller->id;
$methods = [];// public methods 
    foreach (get_class_methods($this) as $m)
        if( preg_match('/^(action[^s])/s', $m))
            $methods[] = $controller.'/'.str_replace('action', '', strtolower($m) );
```

If you need get these method's actions, use this string

```
$action = preg_replace_callback(
                            '/([A-Z+])/s',
                            function ($word)
                            {
                                return strtolower('-'.$word[1]);
                            },
                    $m);
$action = str_replace('action', '', strtolower($action) );
$methods[] = $controller.'/'.substr($action, 1);
```

Comment: need merge inline actions( `action*` methods) and external actions(`actions()` method), use native convertor: `$actionId = Inflector::camel2id(substr($method, 6))`